# Continual training of a pre-trained LLM via LoRa with xTuring

Tags: huggingface-transformers, huggingface, pre-trained-model, huggingface-datasets, llama

I came across the [xTuring library](https://github.com/stochasticai/xturing) reading this [article on the continual training of an LLM](https://www.stochastic.ai/blog/xfinance-vs-bloomberg-gpt). It claims that it continued the training of a pre-trained model in an unsupervised way with `xTuring` via the TextDataset. I'm struggling to understand why the TextDataset takes both a list of inputs and targets as logically it should just take a big block of text for further NSP training I think? Since it uses HuggingFace datasets and PyTorch Lightning under the hood, I'm wondering if this design is due to design patterns imposed by HuggingFace datasets.

```
TextDataset
Here is how you can create this type of dataset:

From a python dictionary with the following keys:

text : List of strings representing the input text.
target : List of strings representing the target text.
from xturing.datasets.text_dataset import TextDataset

dataset = TextDataset({
    "text": ["first text", "second text"],
    "target": ["first text", "second text"]
})
```